# Itemize environment of the enumitem package incompatible with the class{lettre}

Tags: itemize, enumitem, lettre

This problem arises with the french `lettre`, but not with the english `letter`.

When using the `enumitem` package options as `leftmargin=2cm` in the `itemize` environment, an error occurs: `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{lettre}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2cm]
\item premier
\item second
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

By deleting the option `[leftmargin=2cm]`, there is no problem.

How can I use the options of the `enumitem` package with the `itemize` environment in the french `lettre` class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,keepenvs]{lettre}
```

then the class doesn't change `itemize` so `enumitem` isn't confused.  However that may undo some other package changes that you wanted....

Answer (score 4):

The `lettre` class redefines `itemize` which confuses `enumitem`, but keeps `enumerate`. You can switch to `enumerate` and use `label={\textbullet}` for example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,frenchb]{lettre}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=2cm,label={\textbullet}]
\item premier
\item second
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've omitted a screen shot since it does not show anything really exciting ...